# Add XElement to another XElement in specific location

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, xelement

Please consider this `XML`:

```
<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>
```

That is content of a `XElement` variable.Now I have another `XElement` variable with this content:

```
<Person>
    <ID>1001</ID>
    <Name>Aba</Name>
    <LName>Aba</LName>
</Person>
```

I want to add this `XEelemnt` variable to first `XElement` in a specific position (for example as second `Person` tag). How I can do this?

thanks

Comment: have you had the xelement as an object?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: have you loaded the xml string?

Comment: Yes I load it to `XElement`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to load the xml string, second you get the position where you want to insert the xml, then insert the new xml. Here is an example how to do it.

```
var reader = new StringReader(@"<Employees>
    <Person>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <Name>Nima</Name>
        <LName>Agha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <Name>Ligha</Name>
        <LName>Ligha</LName>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <ID>1003</ID>
        <Name>Jigha</Name>
        <LName>Jigha</LName>
    </Person>
</Employees>");
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
xdoc.Element("Employees").
   Elements("Person").
   First().
   AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Person", 
       new XElement("ID", 1001),
       new XElement("Name", "Aba"),
       new XElement("LName", "Aba")));

var sb = new StringBuilder();
var writer = new StringWriter(sb);
xdoc.Save(writer);
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

## UPDATE

If you want to insert by index, just get the element first. For example you want to insert as second position, then you need to get the first index (index = 0).

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
xdoc.Element("Employees").
    Elements("Person").
    ElementAt(0).
    AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Person", 
        new XElement("ID", 1001),
        new XElement("Name", "Aba"),
        new XElement("LName", "Aba")));
```

PS: For simplicity purpose I didn't add nullity check.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to add second xml like your code.I want to add it without knowing `ID=1001` , `Name=Aba` ,... . I want to add my second variable. And I said for example in second position. I want to add that variable in `nth` position of a `XElement`

Comment: the ID=1001 is the new element, to get the first element I used First() then AddAfterSelf, it means it will be inserted as second element.

Comment: Please see First comment. I want to add in `nth` place

Comment: you meant inserting the new element by using index as parameter?